# Numbers are doubled after keylock on/off?

Tags: android

Hy, I'm writing an application and i have a big problem with the keylock while the program runs. In the app there's a page with full of numbers. After I made the keylock on and back to off all the numbers are doubled. for example: 100% after keylock: 200%, 16/16 after keylock 32/32. Could you please help me? 
I don't have any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: My code is too long to copy it. So the point is that I use SharedPreferences in this code. There're 160  boolean type which I got from other activities. I got the boolean type in my onCreate and in the onResume I use them. If the boolean is true then the percentage is growing and point is growing too. When I lock the screen the percentage jump into double value and the points too. Maybe the activity got the booleans again and again? Sorry but this code is about 2000  lines .

Comment: @HowlettLogan Paste the code where you THINK the problem is at least.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **identify** the lines of code causing the error. Nobody can answer this directly w/o any of your code. Not many SO users will even try to read long code blocks.

Save your current code as a backup and reduce it to the relevant lines that produce the error. You will find a solution yourself or you can then post the code.

From your comment I can guess that in method onResume you modify a field variable. If you know the life cycle of android Activity you know that onResume is called each time the activity is shown to the user. The field variable state is preserved and simply **adding** a value each time is not the same as **assigning** a value.